# R reading in data issue

Tags: r

I am reading in this dataset as a csv and I'm not getting any errors but what I am getting is all of the data is being read in as NA when I use "sep = ';'. Anybody know why this might be?
[image]

Comment: please, share your codes and errors.

Comment: This is really strange... your columns seem to import correctly while other rows are merged. Is there any strange character (.,; etc) at the end of the first (header) row? Maybe - what about using `read.csv2("student-mat.csv")` (which uses ";" as default)?

Comment: sometimes it's easier to open up stuff like this in excel, or any other spreadsheet program so you can wrangle the data more hands on before you feed it into R so you can get working

Answer (score 2):

If your dataset is Comma Seperated Values [csv], shouldn't your sep parameter be = ","?
What function are you using to read your data: read.csv or read.delim perhaps?
Also, consider posting some example code next time (and preferably also a chunk of the raw data)